# apache: cpu usage per virtual host

Tags: cpu-usage, apache-http-server

Is there any tool that can provide statistics about cpu-usage per virtual host?
This way I can understand which is the website that causes 100% spikes in CPU usage.
Thanks!

if this is not possible, can I setup apache differently? e.g. each virtualhost running under different user? is this viable or uses much more resources?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such capability in Apache itself.

You can log processing time of request ( noted as %D ) in some custom log and then dig averages and extremes (no CPU consumption accounted). <0.1s is unnoticeable >10s is unbearable according to w3c recommendations.